# Unupvote almost 2 months after upvoting?

Tags: support, reputation, edits, upvotes, locked-votes

On Feb. 20 I placed an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21907882/3001496). A few days ago I noticed a `-10` entry in my reputation list which was an `unupvote` on my answer to this question.

[image: unupvote]

I know that an user can retract an up/downvote some minutes after issuing one and also a longer time when the answer is edited by someone, but is there any other circumstance which may permit retract a vote after such a long time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you edited the post after the vote was cast, the lock is removed and there is *no time limit* on how long afterwards the vote can be undone.

Comment: I thought it was probably this way. Would an account deletion cause this too on any user's issued vote?

Comment: Account deletions undo votes en-masse and are never subject to a vote lock. It's as if the vote was never cast in the first place. All you will see is 'user removed' in your history.